# Adding implementation details, annotations to Swagger definition

Tags: api, swagger-2.0

Is there a standard way to add API implementation details and/or annotations to Swagger definitions?

We are using Swagger to define APIs. However, while we find it a very good tool to define the interface details for the API consumer, we have little capability to define any implementation details for the API developer.

Would like to hear from others on how they are addressing this challenge.